# Expression implicitly coerced from 'UIView?' to Any - How to find line in source code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm getting several warnings in Xcode 8.1 indicating:

```
Expression implicitly coerced from 'UIView?' to Any.
```

There are some for other classes, as well. I had a few of these when I first migrated up to Swift 3, but they were mostly Print statements where I just had to add `as Any` to resolve them. However, the difference with these ones is that they don't take me to any line in the source code, nor do they indicate where in the source code the problem is. If I click on them in Xcode, it just takes me to the log where they are listed again.

[image]

Is there any way for me to determine the code location(s) for these warnings? Thanks.

Edit:

Here's what the warnings look like in the Issue Navigator. If I click on any of them, it does not take me to the line in the source code. It just displays the compiler log with the same messages listed.

[image]

Comment: @rmaddy That's what I get when I click on the warning in the Issue Navigator. It's basically the compiler log. Yes I have looked in the code itself, but scanning through 200,000 lines of code isn't very efficient. Even knowing which file the problem is in would be helpful. I'm wondering if the position in the log would indicate which file.

Comment: I'm ok with the -1, but it would be useful to know why my question was down voted, so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: Yes, I've done Clean, Clean Build Folder, and have cleaned out all Derived Data. If we think it's source control related, is there a way to rebuild the source control version from scratch?

Comment: Thanks. No, that's the problem. None of the lines have the warning on them, and I have gone through and checked every print statement. That's why I said I would have to scan through every line of code, as there is no way to know which line it's complaining about. If you think it has to be a Print statement, then that at least narrows it down a bit for me. I'm leaning toward the re-install of Xcode, or upgrade to the 8.2 beta.

Comment: Oh, i should mention that one of the files that it's complaining about is from an open source library, and there are no Print statements in it at all. Makes it even more confusing :)

Comment: I managed to clean them all up by process of elimination. I commented out the code a block at a time until a warning disappeared, then inspect that block. It turns out that the culprits were dictionary declarations. I added  `as [String : Any]` to the end of each, and it compiles clean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to clean them all up by process of elimination. I commented out the code a block at a time until a warning disappeared, then inspected that block. It turns out that the culprits were dictionary declarations with mixed data types. I added `as [String : Any]` to the end of each, and it compiles clean now.

For example:

```
let params = [
    "myInt"    : 50,
    "myString" : "some stuff",
    "myBool"   : true
]
```

needs to be changed to:

```
let params = [
    "myInt"    : 50,
    "myString" : "some stuff",
    "myBool"   : true
] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: Hmmm. I just tried it in a playground, mixing strings with ints, and, like you, I'm getting an error, suggesting I use "as [String : Any]". Strange that they were just warnings in my actual project. However, I do believe this check was added fairly recently.